# Custom shipping extension

Tags: magento2, shipping

I use Magento 2.4.3.

I created custom shipping extension. It works correct.

But now I would like to add calculating by width, height, length params of product.
I've added these params (width, height, length) to product attribute set. It's easy.

My question - how I can get these these params (width, height, length) in method `collectRates()` my custom shipping extrension?

I see `$request->getPackageWeight()`, `$request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax()`. Is there method(s) to get custom product attribute in `$request`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly in request there is no such value. But you can get quote items `$request->getAllItems()` . Do foreach, get item, then product from it (or load it by id/sku) and get required values from product.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was helpful to me.